# Putting Views inside a Fragment at run time

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Activity. This activity has a fragment inside it.
The fragment layout

```
<?xml 

version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".foo">
</FrameLayout>
```

How can I get this FrameLayout from my Activity (that is using the fragment) and add some views (buttons and edit boxes inside it). And update my Activity?

Comment: do you mean to create them programmatically?

Comment: @D.'s the views yes, the fragment no :) also I would be grateful if you link me some tutorial for programmatically adding views, with some margins etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is to start from the basics,you can go [at google documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout) to learn all types of layout's.

All elements in the layout are built using a hierarchy of View and ViewGroup objects. A View usually draws something the user can see and interact with.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Hello, I am a TextView" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello, I am a Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In your case since you are using `FrameLayout` is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item.

Generally, [FrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout) should be used to hold a single child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other.

Hope it helps!